# Calculation of multivariate probability mass function

Tags: probability, random-variable, multivariate-distribution, discrete-distributions

How to calculate the following multivariate probability mass function:

$P(X_1-X = n, X_2-X = n, ..., X_{N-1}-X = n)$

Where $n$ and $N$ are positive integers, and $X_i$ and $X$ are iid random variables with the following discrete probability distribution:

$P(i)=\frac{C_{i-1}}{2^{2i-1}}$;  $C_{i}$ are Catalan numbers.

Looking at: [Integrating pdf times cdf squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236620/integrating-pdf-times-cdf-squared/526476#526476) and walking backwards, from multivariate to integral representation I got:

$ \sum _{i=0} ^{+ \infty} {P(i)P(i+n)^{N-1}}$

However, it appears that the last formula gives me correct results only for N=2. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If these are independent random variables, you can work out the answer by conditioning on the value of $X$.

Comment: They are iids, I have amended the question. I have also added something I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start of your solution looks correct to me. We have
$$
\begin{align}
p & = P(X_1-X = n, \ldots , X_{N-1}-X = n ) \\
& = 
\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X_1-X = n, \ldots , X_{N-1}-X = n | X = i) P(X = i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X_1 = n+i, \ldots , X_{N-1} = n+i) P(X = i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_X(n+i)^{N-1} f_X(i)
\end{align}
$$
by independence, where $f_X$ is the PMF. Substituting in $f_X(i)$ gives
$$
p = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[\frac{C_{n+i-1}}{2^{2(n+i)-1}} \right]^{N-1} \frac{C_{i-1}}{2^{2i-1}}
$$